# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>301 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

```
public class NetworkUtils {
    private static final String urlS = "http://gitlab.65apps.com/65gb/static/raw/master/testTask.json";

    public static JSONObject getJSONFromNetwork () {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlS);
            Log.i("url", url.toString());
            jsonObject = new JSONLoadTask().execute(url).get();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }

    private static class JSONLoadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            JSONObject result = null;
            if(urls == null || urls.length == 0) {
                return result;
            }
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls[0].openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    Log.i("Reslt", line);
                    builder.append(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }

                result = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(connection != null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        JSONObject jsonObject = NetworkUtils.getJSONFromNetwork();
        if(jsonObject == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Hello! I ask for your help!
I've recently started to study Android.
Now I try to write a little app for training myself and run into Error which I can't fix.
In Logcat I see this:

> `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>301 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

From my URL I receive this (key words for watch what I try to convert into JSONObject "Reslt"):

```
2021-03-01 13:38:02.707 14467-14467/com.example.myemployees I/url: http://gitlab.65apps.com/65gb/static/raw/master/testTask.json
2021-03-01 13:38:02.712 14467-14501/com.example.myemployees D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-03-01 13:38:02.854 14467-14501/com.example.myemployees I/Reslt: <html>
2021-03-01 13:38:02.854 14467-14501/com.example.myemployees I/Reslt: <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
2021-03-01 13:38:02.854 14467-14501/com.example.myemployees I/Reslt: <body>
2021-03-01 13:38:02.854 14467-14501/com.example.myemployees I/Reslt: <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
2021-03-01 13:38:02.854 14467-14501/com.example.myemployees I/Reslt: <hr><center>nginx</center>
2021-03-01 13:38:02.854 14467-14501/com.example.myemployees I/Reslt: </body>
2021-03-01 13:38:02.854 14467-14501/com.example.myemployees I/Reslt: </html>
2021-03-01 13:38:02.855 14467-14501/com.example.myemployees W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>301 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

URL works correct if I open this address but instead of get correct String to convert it I receive something strange.

In my activity I I always receive Toast : "Error" that means:  jsonObject == null.

Comment: 301 moved means the site can ve found somewhere else.

Comment: URL works correct if I open this adress but instead of get correct String to convert it I recieve something strange: I/Reslt: <html>    I/Reslt: <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>    I/Reslt: <body>    I/Reslt: <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>    I/Reslt: <hr><center>nginx</center>    I/Reslt: </body>    I/Reslt: </html>

Comment: This "strange string" is an informative message telling you that the json file is licated somewhere else.

Comment: It means that the resource you want to obtain has been moved. You must make another request to the new address. Http redirects are common and normal. In your case, you could point your app towards the new address or in your code handle the redirects (in case it has changed, go to the new returned address)

Comment: I think the problem is that you used `http://` instead of `https://`

Comment: Thank you for yours help! When I changed http:// instead of https:// it works correct!